How to Create next and previous buttons in Wordpress or html that allow it to go through all the pages in the site
I have a series of pages, lets call them say I have a series of pages with this example name ("x_1.html","x_2.html","x_3.html", and so on) and I want to have next/prev buttons leading to each. I don't want any extra pagination, just prev and next button.
I also want these pages once the end is reached, to loop back so "x_50.html" would naturally loop back to the beginning "x_1.html".
There should be links in the menus for all the pages I want it to go to.  But I want to be able to do so if possible with JavaScript or without php, or server side data fetching? I’m not very good with either JavaScript or php
Thank you for your help.
I tried several different Wordpress plugins and after trying many different ones was unable to find one that did what I wanted.  I expected it to be a easy problem that there would be an easy plug in for but have had a lot of trouble trying different ones and troubleshooting only to have to start over again.  Some said they would work but then had a large amount of php work you had to do, which I am not very skilled with.

Do you want this pagination in pure HTML or Wordpress?

Wordpress is prefered but I’d also be fine with html.  Thank you

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I dont understand, that do you want to make a code for the WordPress site or do you have HTML pages for that? Kindly share your code...
